# Prevent inverted Flatlist from scrolling to bottom when new items are added

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am building a chat app, using an inverted `Flatlist`. I add new items to the top of the list when `onEndReached` is called and everything works fine.

The problem is that if add items to the bottom, it instantly scrolls to the bottom of the list. That means that the user has to scroll back up to read the messages that were just added (which is terrible).

I tried to call `scrollToOffset` in `onContentSizeChange`, but this has a one-second delay where the scroll jumps back and forth.

How can I have the list behave **the same way when I add items to the top AND to the bottom**, by keeping the same messages on screen instead of showing the new ones?

Answer (score 6):

here is demo: https://snack.expo.io/@nomi9995/flatlisttest

**Solution 1:**

use [maintainVisibleContentPosition](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#maintainvisiblecontentposition) props for preventing auto-scroll, Note: maintainVisibleContentPosition was added in android recently so you should have to use latest version of react native

```
<FlatList
  ref={(ref) => { this.chatFlatList = ref; }}
  style={styles.flatList}
  data={this.state.items}
  renderItem={this._renderItem}
  maintainVisibleContentPosition={{
     minIndexForVisible: 0,
  }}
/>
```

**Solution 2:**

I found another workaround by keep latest y offset with [onScroll](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscroll) and also save content height before and after adding new items with [onContentSizeChange](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#oncontentsizechange) and calculate the difference of content height, and set new y offset to the latest y offset + content height difference!

Comment: Unfortunately, I need something that works on both iOs and Android. In the description of my issue, I pointed out that I tried to use onContentSizeChange, but this provokes a jump to the bottom first, followed by a jump back to where I want the scroll to be. This method seems to only work with lists of light components, without complex separators (like I have).

Comment: can you add gif or video in question? maintainVisibleContentPosition work on android and for ios we have to make native code

Comment: if chat message add on top of list then you want to move to top and if chat message add on bootm of list then you want tom move on bottom?

Comment: I never want to move to the top or to the bottom, in any case. I want what is on the screen to always stays on the screen, no matter if I append or prepend data to my list. Basically the behavior of every chat app.

Comment: I have update demo you can test ios https://snack.expo.io/@nomi9995/flatlisttest . i will try to make native code to achieve this at night

Comment: Thank you :). Maybe native code will be useful for others that find this question, but it won't help in my case as I am using Expo and can't write native code.

Comment: okay but now you can test ios. i will try to make solutuion for android and edit my answer

Comment: I try to make a native solution but failed due to some native uimanager view issue. can i make special dynamic android solution in js

Comment: Yes, I am facing the same issue on my side can anybody tell me the solution to this by maintaining the screen on the previous position instead of the new position by adding items in the data array of the flat list.

Comment: Solution 2 is not a good way, because it has a UX problem. Firstly it scrolls down and after that scrolls back to the latest position
And it's not working when I want to load my list item from the realm database.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am adding a new item on top and bottom in an **inverted Flatlist**.

[image]

I hope you can compare your requirements with the provided sample code :)

## **Full Code:**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Button,
  Platform,
  UIManager,
  LayoutAnimation,
} from 'react-native';

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  if (UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental) {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
  }
}

const getRandomColor = () => {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
};

const DATA = [
  getRandomColor(),
  getRandomColor(),
  getRandomColor(),
  getRandomColor(),
  getRandomColor(),
];

export default class App extends Component {
  scrollValue = 0;
  append = true;

  state = {
    data: DATA,
  };

  addItem = (top) => {
    const {data} = this.state;
    let newData;
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    if (top) {
      newData = [...data, getRandomColor()];
      this.setState({data: newData});
    } else {
      newData = [getRandomColor(), ...data];
      this.setState({data: newData});
    }
  };

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return this.scrollValue === 0 || this.append;
  }

  onScrollBeginDrag = () => {
    this.append = true;
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    this.setState({});
  };

  render() {
    const {data} = this.state;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="ADD ON TOP" onPress={() => this.addItem(true)} />
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          onScrollBeginDrag={this.onScrollBeginDrag}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Item item={item} />}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item}
          inverted
          onScroll={(e) => {
            this.append = false;
            this.scrollValue = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
          }}
        />
        <Button title="ADD ON BOTTOM" onPress={() => this.addItem(false)} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

function Item({item}) {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.item, {backgroundColor: item}]}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{item}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    height: 100,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a solution for when the size of the content added is unknown? as it is a chat app,  all messages do not have the same height. I tried using the "onContentSizeChange" callback, but this has a delay where it will jump to the bottom and then back to where it should go.

Comment: I think the only way is to stop rendering of flatlist if the scroll position is not 0 (using shouldComponentUpdate).

Comment: Just edited the code section. you can set minimun scroll position to append data.
eg, change this.scrollValue === 0 to this.scrollValue < 100.

Answer (score 1):

This is one year late, but this works fine:

```
        <FlatList
          inverted
          initialScrollIndex={1}
          {...}
        />
```

Since inverted renders flatlist but with `inverted: 1`, thus you need to pass 1 to `initialScrollIndex` so that it scrolls to bottom in normal list and to top in the inverted one

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using keyExtractor?
It may help react avoid re-render, so try use unique keys for each item.
you can read more about it here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#keyextractor

Comment: Yes, I am using the keyExtractor with unique keys for each item. The jumping doesn't happen when I add items to the top, only to the bottom. I believe it might be the intended behavior of the inverted list, which I want to block.